# Excel Validation for Insert operation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

An excel consist of several sheets(say 2 or 3) have some mandatory columns to avoid the columns to be left *blank*.

is there any mechanism of *data validation/formula* by which if those columns of a sheet not filled then while saving/closing it should throw an error alert ?I want to implement a control mechanism so that a user must fill these fields if he/she is doing any insert operation in the sheet.

**Example :**
Sheet 1 consist of 5 columns (A,B,C,D,E).
Out of these 5 columns I want column B,C,D should not be left blank when a user is performing *insert operation in the sheet*.

Comment: Using excel validation, no it isn't foolproof. Using VBA, yes you can implement a control like that and prevent someone from saving the file before filling in those required columns.

Comment: What you can use is the `Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)` event listener. If a person did not fill up the required cells, set `Cancel=TRUE` and the workbook will not save or even close.

Comment: Hope this points you to the right direction you can google them as there are many reference to using that VBA code.

Comment: Have a range of cells that check for valid entries - if just one is false....